# Formula Help -- Pull Reference From Horizontal Array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a horizontal data set that I am needing to reference based on the specific visit #. For example, in the picture below I'm looking to create a formula in **G22** that will look at B22 (Name), C22 (ID #), and reference C4 that it is the second visit. How should I go about this?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't D4 and D5 have values 3 and 4 respectively? Otherwise I do not understand how the IDs work?

Comment: Initial Visit documents all ID #s (they're leaking), second visit checks up on the ID #s found in the initial visit to see if they have been repaired, if they were not, they are visited a third time. If that makes sense. Each visit is shown as a row. The Visit # indicated where they are in the process

Comment: I would like to mention that you can code your own formulas inside a VBA Macro. You can use your macro like you would use a normal formula then. [Example](https://best-excel-tutorial.com/57-vba-tutorial/225-create-own-function-vba) That Way you can handle even more complex stuff way easier.

Comment: you most likely need to introduce a Unique ID per visit... and move from there...
This sheet does not have any unique value to match...
P.S. you can try to CONCATENATE the unique ID using B,C,D values and use it in Index/Match formula... but you have space in Col "A" for that, to make end formula easier to read